# Less clunky way of checking a string for comma separation in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to check a string for comma separation. After I check the string, I'm going to use it to help load a SQL database so the words in the string can't be separated by anything other than a comma. I do have an approach that works but it seems very clunky for Python. Is there a more concise/less expensive way to check a string for comma separation?

Here's my attempt run in a Python 2.7.4 interpreter:

```
# List of possible Strings
comma_check_list = ['hello, world', 'hello world', 'hello,  world',\ 
                    'hello world, good, morning']

# Dictionary of punctuation that's not a comma
 punct_dict = {'@': True, '^': True, '!': True, ' ': True, '#': True, '%': True,\
               '$': True, '&': True, ')': True, '(': True, '+': True, '*': True,\ 
               '-': True, '=': True}

# Function to check the string
def string_check(comma_check_list, punct_dict):
    for string in comma_check_list:
        new_list = string.split(", ")
        if char_check(new_list, punct_dict) == False:
            print string, False
        else:
            print string, True

# Function to check each character
def char_check(new_list, punct_dict):
    for item in new_list:
        for char in item:
            if char in punct_dict:
                return False

# Usage
string_check(comma_check_list, punct_dict)

# Output
hello, world True
hello world False
hello,  world False
hello world, good, morning False
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: From your examples I have no idea why the first one is `True`, and the last two are `False`. What do you mean by "comma separation"?

Comment: Use a dict comprehension to make `punct_dict`: `punct_dict = { x:True for x in "@^! #%$&)(+*-="}`.

Comment: @millimoose for the SQL query I would want something like: SELECT hello, world FROM table; So by comma separation I mean ", " and nothing else

Comment: Don't blacklist, whitelist. Check whether the "words" in the string are only valid SQL identifiers.

Comment: Could you add a comment? That may be the best answer

Comment: @Tyler Working on it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably reduce your code to the following.

```
# List of possible Strings
comma_check_list = ['hello, world', 'hello world', 'hello,  world', 'hello world, good, morning']

# Dictionary of punctuation that's not a comma
punct = set('@^! #%$&)(+*-="')

# Function to check the string
def string_check(comma_check_list, punct):
    for string in comma_check_list:
        new_list = string.split(", ")
        print string, not any(char in punct for item in new_list for char in item)

# Usage
string_check(comma_check_list, punct)
```

Changes made.

1. Used a `set` since you are using the dictionary for look ups only.
2. Used `any`.
3. Print instead of the `if` condition.

Output

```
In [6]: %run 
hello, world True
hello world False
hello,  world False
hello world, good, morning False
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for currentString in comma_check_list:
    if any(True for char in currentString if char in '@^! #%$&)(+*-="'):
        print currentString, False
    else:
        print currentString, True
```

`@^! #%$&)(+*-="` are the characters you dont want them in the string. So, if any of the characters in the `currentString` is in that list, we will print `False`.

Comment: +1: Although the list of characters is longer, it might be better to use `string.punctuation.replace(',', '')` instead of hardcoding a literal like that into your code. The result would be something like ``'!"#$%&\'()*+-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'``.

Answer (score 2):

You should whitelist for valid SQL identifiers instead:

```
import re

ID_RE = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9$]+$')

def is_sql_columns(columns):
    return all(ID_RE.match(column_name.strip()) 
               for column_name in columns.split(','))

### Test cases ###

def main():
    test = [
        'hello,world',     # True
        ' hello , world ', # True
        'hello world',     # False
        '!@#$%^&*,yuti',   # False
        'hello',           # True
        'hello,',          # False
        'a!b,c@d',         # False
        ''                 # False
    ]

    for t in test:
        print '{!r:>16}{!r:>8}'.format(t, is_sql_columns(t))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is a conservative RE for valid identifiers [in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), it doesn't handle non-ASCII letters or quoted identifiers. It will also allow extra spaces between the words since those don't matter in SQL anyway.

Also remember that this will reject valid column lists for a `SELECT` that use column aliases.  (E.g. `SELECT first_name AS fname, last_name lname…`)

Comment: example output: is_sql_columns(comma_check_list[0]) True

Comment: This approach doesn't return False for comma_check_list[1] or comma_check_list[3] so I'm thinking this could work with another for loop

Comment: @Tyler I added a few more test cases, maybe those cover it. I do see one broken thing though.

Comment: @Tyler Right, my regexp was wrong, this seems to do the right thing. (Which is not exactly the same as your original code, but should be correct for what you said you want to do.)